# AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION в Dagger

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, dagger2, dagger

Начинаю изучать Dagger, пробую создать простое приложение

Вылетает ошибка:

```
    2022-09-14 12:31:33.949 27287-27287/com.sem.daggersimple E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.sem.daggersimple, PID: 27287
        java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8192KB
            at android.app.ContextImpl.getApplicationContext(ContextImpl.java:357)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:122)
            at com.sem.daggersimple.presentation.di.AppKt.getAppComponent(App.kt:20)
            at com.sem.daggersimple.presentation.di.AppKt.getAppComponent(App.kt:20)
            at com.sem.daggersimple.presentation.di.AppKt.getAppComponent(App.kt:20)

...

at com.sem.daggersimple.presentation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:16)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8017)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8001)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1310)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3423)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3602)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2067)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
2022-09-14 12:31:34.435 27287-27303/? W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
2022-09-14 12:31:34.435 27287-27303/? W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
2022-09-14 12:31:34.503 27287-27287/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27287 SIG: 9
```

`App.kt:20` указывает на строку `else -> this.applicationContext.appComponent`

`MainActivity`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        appComponent.inject(this)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

    }
}
```

`StringFragment`:

```
class StringFragment : Fragment() {

    private var binding : FragmentStringBinding? = null

    @Inject
    lateinit var stringViewModel: StringViewModel

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        
        // Grabs the registrationComponent from the Activity and injects this Fragment
       // (activity as MainActivity).
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_string, container, false)

        binding?.textView?.text = stringViewModel.getString

        return binding?.root
    }

}
```

`StringRepository`:

```
class StringRepository @Inject constructor() {

    override fun toString() = "какой-то текст"

}
```

`StringUseCase`:

```
class StringUseCase @Inject constructor(private val repository: StringRepository) {

    fun getString() : String {
        return repository.toString()
    }

}
```

`StringViewModel`:

```
class StringViewModel @Inject constructor(private val stringUseCase: StringUseCase) : ViewModel() {

    val getString = stringUseCase.getString()

}
```

`App`:

```
class App : Application() {

    lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.create()
    }

}

val Context.appComponent: AppComponent
    get() = when(this) {
        is App -> appComponent
        else -> this.applicationContext.appComponent
    }
```

`AppComponent`:

```
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
    fun inject(stringFragment: StringFragment)

}
```

`AppModule`:

```
@Module
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideStringViewModel(stringUseCase: StringUseCase) : StringViewModel {

        return StringViewModel(stringUseCase)

    }

    @Provides
    fun provideStringUseCase(repository: StringRepository) : StringUseCase {
        return StringUseCase(repository)
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideStringRepository() : StringRepository {
        return StringRepository()
    }

}
```

Comment: Рекурсия у вас: геттер вызывает сам себя, потому что имена свойств одинаковые. С котлиным не особо дружу, мои предположения - переименовать одно из них или привести к целевому типу: что-то вроде `(this.applicationContext as App).appComponent`

Comment: @woesss, смена имени не помогла, привести к целевому типу тоже не получилось, пишет `android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.sem.daggersimple.presentation.di.App`

Comment: А вы свой `App` в манифесте прописали? Без этого он не задействуется, а используется стандартный `android.app.Application`

Comment: @woesss, как оказалось, я и вправду забыл прописать App в манифесте, спасибо!

Comment: @woesss, также, по какой-то причине, нужно закоментировать строку `binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)` в `MainActivity`, иначе приложение тоже будет вылетать